# How to navigate to htdocs of XAMPP in MacOSX via the terminal

Tags: macos, xampp, htdocs

I have installed XAMPP in my Mac OSX El Captain. Now I need to navigate to the htdocs via the command line. I am very new to this. Can someone help me on the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

1. open application folder
2. find xampp folder at bottom
3. get inside and findout htdocs folder
4. open terminal
5. drag the htdocs folder to terminal

you will get the path

Answer (score 6):

Go to terminal and type the following... High Siera 10.13.3

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs
```

Answer (score 3):

type `cd /Users/apple/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs`

Answer (score 1):

> cd
>   /Users/{username}/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs

Answer (score 1):

If you launched the terminal using the XAMPP interface, then it opens the directories of the virtual machine. In that case, the folder location of web root is /opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 0):

After install go to Xampp > volumes > Mount, after that
Click on Explore and find "htdocs" folder.